# how do i get client ip address in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

By using below code I am able to get client IP address.

But I want to get client IP address in **javascript** without using any external website **http://** or **https://** urls.

How do I get client IP address?

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
    alert("Your ip: " + data.ip);
});
```

java is server side language.

Please help me.

Comment: Given your existing code, it looks like your question is "Can you recommend a service that will tell me the client IP over SSL?", and product recommendation questions are off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: i need over the ssl url site.. can u tell me..

Comment: I just said it was off-topic for this site, so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a server side page on your site return the IP address, you don't want to be making external calls, especially to http otherwise you'll get browser warnings.

```
$.getJSON("getIPFromThisJSONPage.aspx", function (data) {
    alert("Your ip: " + data.ip);
});
```

OR

```
$.get("getIPFromThisAjaxPage.aspx",function(data){
    return data;
});
```

You don't mention what your using as a server side language so not much point in providing an example - besides ajax/json examples are a dime a dozen :)

Comment: Am using java  as server side language